# Braces spanning to next page

Tags: margins, overleaf, brackets, braces, schemata

I am trying to put braces along long text but the text and brace disppears at the end of page as shown at the bottom of figure.
Ideally the text and brace should continue from next page.

Here is an example to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\BrText[2]{%
  \par\smallskip
   \noindent\makebox[\textwidth][r]{$\text{#1}\left\{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    #2
    \end{minipage}
  \right.\nulldelimiterspace=0pt$}\par\smallskip
}    

\begin{document}
\BrText{Some text}{\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1] \lipsum[1] \lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also be a bit more specific about your actual use-case? For example, does your actual text start at the top of the text block, or is it just in the middle of the page and then runs onto the next? Regardless, how do you want to handle the cusp and text in situations where the brace covers more text on the second page than the first? Could the text span more than two pages?

Comment: The text starts from the top of the page and then it spans to the middle of next page. The brace should cover the text from start and till the middle of the  next page. In other other words, the brace should cover until the paragraph ends which is at the middle of next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code inserts two separate, broken braces using a combination of packages:

- [`abraces`](//ctan.org/pkg/abraces): For asymmetric (and broken) braces;
- [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module: For capturing of coordinates within the text;
- [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic): For placement of content within the page `F`ore`G`round (or `B`ack`G`round), on a single page or all pages; and
- [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx): For rotating content.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{abraces,zref-savepos,eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]% Some text before start of brace

% Insert first page, broken left brace
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{%
    \zsavepos{textblock-bottom}% Capture bottom of text block coordinate
    \raisebox{-.2\baselineskip}{%
      \makebox[0pt][r]{%
        \rotatebox{90}{%
          $\aoverbrace[1U1R]{\hspace{\dimexpr\zposy{brace-top}sp-\zposy{textblock-bottom}sp+\baselineskip}}^{\rotatebox{-90}{\scriptsize some text}}$%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%

\leavevmode\zsavepos{brace-top}%
This text starts somewhere on this page.

\lipsum[2-7]

% Insert half-page, broken left brace
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\zposy{brace-bottom}sp-\zposy{textblock-bottom}sp}{%
      \makebox[0pt][r]{%
        \rotatebox{90}{%
          $\aoverbrace[L1]{\hspace{\dimexpr\textheight-\zposy{brace-bottom}sp+\zposy{textblock-bottom}sp}}$%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\leavevmode\zsavepos{brace-bottom}%
This text is in the middle of the second page.

\lipsum[8-15]

\end{document}
```

`abraces`' `\aoverbrace[<brace spec>]` takes a character sequence as an optional `<brace spec>`ification, similar to how `tabular` requires a character sequence for its column specification. Specifically, here's the meaning of the characters (taken from the [`abraces` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/abraces)):

[image]

The places where the brace start (`brace-top`) and ends (`brace-bottom`) are captured (including a `textblock-bottom` as reference) and used to calculate the brace length/height and then rotated into place.

Comment: Beautiful! Almost there.  The above code put the braces from the top then the middle page. What if the desired paragraph starts from the middle of the first page and ends with middle of next page? Please excuse me if i communcated mistakely earlier.

Comment: @CaseMsee: See the updated answer.

Comment: Can we manually select the braces for specific paragrapgh thar are spanning ti next page instead of selecting top-middle sections in code?

Comment: @CaseMsee: Yeah, I changed it using `top` and `bottom` (not `middle`) attributes. :) True, you can do whatever, but you'll have to provide some more clarity in terms of what you mean by "the braces [should span] specific paragraphs..." Perhaps you can draw a picture and include it here?